# Firefox's Web extension "browser" variable

Tags: javascript, browser, mozilla

I have a problem that I cannot explain at all...

I have a line in my code like this:

```
port = browser.runtime.connect({name:"xxx"});
```

The problem is, when I try to execute it, I get the console error:

```
ReferenceError: browser is not defined
```

I've Googled a lot, without success. I hope somebody can give me a tip.

Answer (score 0):

Since browser is not defined, and there is an add-on where the variable runtime is defined, try:

```
 port = runtime.connect({name:"xxx"});
```

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime
Is that what you are working with?